# pandas - series.str.extract is dropping the first character of the capture group

Tags: python, regex, pandas, data-cleaning

I need to extract the dates from the next Series:

---

0        03/25/93 Total time of visit (in minutes):\n
1                        6/18/85 Primary Care Doctor:\n
2     sshe plans to move as of 7/8/71 In-Home Servic...
3                 7 on 9/27/75 Audit C Score Current:\n
4     2/6/96 sleep studyPain Treatment Pain Level (N...
5                     .Per 7/06/79 Movement D/O note:\n
6     4, 5/18/78 Patient's thoughts about current su...
7     10/24/89 CPT Code: 90801 - Psychiatric Diagnos...
8                          3/7/86 SOS-10 Total Score:\n
9              (4/10/71)Score-1Audit C Score Current:\n
10    (5/11/85) Crt-1.96, BUN-26; AST/ALT-16/22; WBC...
11                        4/09/75 SOS-10 Total Score:\n
12    8/01/98 Communication with referring physician...
13    1/26/72 Communication with referring physician...
14    5/24/1990 CPT Code: 90792: With medical servic...
15    1/25/2011 CPT Code: 90792: With medical servic...
16          4/12/82 Total time of visit (in minutes):\n
17         1; 10/13/1976 Audit C Score, Highest/Date:\n

---

I am trying it so with the following regex

df.str.extract('.*(\d{1,4}/\d{1,4}/\d{1,4}).*')

But why is it dropping the first number in the first couple of numbers since I am specifying {1,4}?

For example, from row 7 an 17, it should extract '10/24/89' and '10/13/1976' respectively, instead of '0/24/89' and '0/13/1976'

I am also trying with adding a '?:' at the beginning of the capture group but it does not work

Thanks beforehand!

Comment: I think you are facing a RegEx "greedy" vs "lazy" problem.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/2301285/6361531

Comment: Wow! that was a fast response Scott. I only had to add a '?' after the asterisk. Thank you very much!

df.str.extract('.\*?(\d{1,4}/\d{1,4}/\d{1,4}).\*')

Answer (score 0):

I would put word boundaries around the dates, i.e. use this pattern:

```
\b(\d+/\d+/\d+)\b
```

Update code:

```
df['date'] = df['col'].str.extract('\b(\d+/\d+/\d+)\b')
```

Here is a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TKeTf2/1) showing that the above pattern be working correctly.